# Winston only writes to a single transport

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using a custom `winston` logger to simultaneously write to the console and to a file depending on the logging level (i.e. anything to the console but only errors and warnings to the file). For some reason writing to the console works while nothing gets written to the file, even though I call an error.

Initially I messed up the order of the levels, starting from `trace` = 0 going up to `error` = 9. While I had that setup `winston` wrote to the file but not to the console. I assume `winston` only writes to one transport and then stops?

My config goes like this:

```
import winston from 'winston';

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  levels: {
    trace: 9,
    input: 8,
    verbose: 7,
    prompt: 6,
    debug: 5,
    info: 4,
    data: 3,
    help: 2,
    warn: 1,
    error: 0,
  },
  colors: {
    trace: 'magenta',
    input: 'grey',
    verbose: 'cyan',
    prompt: 'grey',
    debug: 'blue',
    info: 'green',
    data: 'grey',
    help: 'cyan',
    warn: 'yellow',
    error: 'red',
  },
});

logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  level: 'trace',
  prettyPrint: true,
  colorize: true,
  silent: false,
  timestamp: false,
});

logger.add(winston.transports.File, {
  prettyPrint: false,
  level: 'error',
  silent: false,
  colorize: true,
  timestamp: true,
  filename: `${__dirname}/../logs/error.log`,
  maxsize: 40000,
  maxFiles: 10,
  json: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to give each transport a name. I.e.

```
logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  name: 'trace-console',
  // ...
});

logger.add(winston.transports.File, {
  name: 'error-file',
  // ...
});
```

Now it seems to work as expected.

*edit: For some reason, both must have the `colorize` option set to be true too (?).*